# WPF - artifacts on bitmap image on resize

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, canvas, bitmap

I am implementing error diffusion algorithm (color reduction) in C# (WPF) and I am using writeableBitmap.
Following function opens new window with computed image:

```
private void OpenNewWindow()
{
    // TODO: Bug with image resizes
    const int margin = 50;
    currAlgWindow = new Window { Owner = this };
    var w = algorithmBitmap.Width;
    var h = algorithmBitmap.Height;
    var canvas = new Canvas { Width = w + margin * 2, Height = h + margin * 2 };


    var img = new Image { Source = algorithmBitmap };
    Canvas.SetLeft(img, (canvas.Width - w) / 2);
    Canvas.SetTop(img, (canvas.Height - h) / 2);
    canvas.Children.Add(img);

    currAlgWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
    currAlgWindow.Content = canvas;
    currAlgWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    currAlgWindow.Show();
}
```

And I am getting weirdest issue I have ever encountered, because on resize of the new Window, assigned image **changes** even though there no `onSizeChanged` events attached anywhere. 
Example: 
1. Image right after `currAlgWindow.Show()`
[image: Image right after <code>currAlgWindow.Show()</code>] 
2. Image after resizing the window. 
[image: Image after resizing the window] 
3. Image after further resizing 
[image: Image after further resizing]

Moving the window also changes the image a bit (refresh is visible). 
All the issues does not occur on the original image, only on the computed one. 

I am also providing the code of algorithm:

```
public abstract class Algorithm
{
    protected WriteableBitmap bitmap;
    protected byte[] originalCopy;
    protected int bytesPerPixel;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;

    protected Algorithm()
    {
    }

    public virtual WriteableBitmap Bitmap
    {
        get => bitmap; 
        set 
        {
            bitmap = value;
            bytesPerPixel = (bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
            width = bitmap.PixelWidth;
            height = bitmap.PixelHeight;

            originalCopy = new byte[height * bitmap.BackBufferStride];
            bitmap.CopyPixels(originalCopy, bitmap.BackBufferStride, 0);
        }
    }

    public abstract void Apply(int Kr, int Kg, int Kb);

    protected static int RoundToNeareastMultiple(int num, int multiple)
    {
        return (int)(((num + multiple / 2) / multiple) * multiple);
    }
}
```

```
public class ErrorDiffusionDithering : Algorithm
{
    public ErrorDiffusionDithering(WriteableBitmap imageBitmap)
    {
        this.Bitmap = imageBitmap;
    }

    public override void Apply(int Kr, int Kg, int Kb)
    {
        int itR = 255 / (Kr - 1);
        int itG = 255 / (Kg - 1);
        int itB = 255 / (Kb - 1);
        var bmpRect = new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height);
        bitmap.WritePixels(bmpRect, originalCopy, bitmap.BackBufferStride, 0); // Copy cached original image

        bitmap.Lock();

        unsafe
        {
            byte* bmpArray = (byte*)bitmap.BackBuffer.ToPointer();
            for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
            {
                byte* currPos = bmpArray + i * bitmap.BackBufferStride;
                Position row = GetPos(i, height);
                for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
                {
                    Position col = GetPos(j, width);

                    byte newVal = RoundToNeareastMultiple(currPos[0], itB).ToByte();
                    PropagateError(currPos[0] - newVal, 0, currPos, row, col);
                    currPos[0] = newVal;

                    newVal = RoundToNeareastMultiple(currPos[1], itG).ToByte();
                    PropagateError(currPos[1] - newVal, 1, currPos, row, col);
                    currPos[1] = newVal;

                    newVal = RoundToNeareastMultiple(currPos[2], itR).ToByte();
                    PropagateError(currPos[2] - newVal, 2, currPos, row, col);
                    currPos[2] = newVal;

                    currPos += bytesPerPixel;
                }
            }
        }
        bitmap.AddDirtyRect(bmpRect);

        bitmap.Unlock();
    }


    private unsafe void PropagateError(int error, int colorNum, byte* currPos, Position row, Position col)
    {
        // x - from left to right
        // y - from top to bottom

        int ind;
        if (col != Position.Last)
        {
            ind = bytesPerPixel + colorNum;
            // pixel[x + 1][y] := pixel[x + 1][y] + quant_error * 7 / 16
            currPos[ind] = (currPos[ind] + ((error * 7) >> 4)).ToByte();
        }

        if (row != Position.Last)
        {
            if (col != Position.First)
            {
                ind = bitmap.BackBufferStride - bytesPerPixel + colorNum;
                // pixel[x - 1][y + 1] := pixel[x - 1][y + 1] + quant_error * 3 / 16
                currPos[ind] = (currPos[ind] + ((error * 3) >> 4)).ToByte();
            }

            ind = bitmap.BackBufferStride + colorNum;
            // pixel[x][y + 1] := pixel[x][y + 1] + quant_error * 5 / 16
            currPos[ind] = (currPos[ind] + ((error * 5) >> 4)).ToByte();

            if (col != Position.Last)
            {
                ind = bitmap.BackBufferStride + bytesPerPixel + colorNum;
                //pixel[x + 1][y + 1] := pixel[x + 1][y + 1] + quant_error * 1 / 16
                currPos[ind] = (currPos[ind] + ((error * 1) >> 4)).ToByte();
            }
        }
    }

    private enum Position { First, Last, Other };

    private Position GetPos(int r, int dim)
    {
        return r == dim - 1 ? Position.Last : r == 0 ? Position.First : Position.Other;
    }
}
```

Also the artifacts looks differently on the pictures that you can see here than on my computer - like after saving it to different format it is displayed in other way. 
I also tested app on a different computer and there the issue does not occur.

 
I am completely confused about what is really the cause of my problem - screen, system, software, code?

Comment: `var img = new Image { Source = algorithmBitmap, Strech = Stretch.None };` Disable stretching it may fiddle your image. Since `Image` has default value of Uniform.

Comment: @Eldar Note that a Canvas does not resize its child elements - even if it would not have itself a fixed size like it has here. The Image element is never stretched.

Comment: What PixelFormat is the WriteableBitmap?

Comment: _"assigned image changes"_ -- please be more specific. Are you saying that the _assignment_ itself changes? Or just the image? Either way, _in what way_ did it change, **specifically**? It is not unusual for an image to be drawn at a different size as its container is resized, depending on the layout configuration. You need to provide more details and include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Changes in the way I provided on pictures - it is redrawn differently. What I specifically did was resizing the window, to which image is assigned.

Comment: Format of WriteableBitmap is Bgr32, it is converted from Indexed8 in my program - original is standard 8bit Lena in grey scale.

Comment: @Eldar as Clemens noted, `Strech = Stretch.None` doesn't change anything. Image is not visibly resized when I resize the window.

Comment: You may try to get rid of any rendering artifacts by setting UseLayoutRounding to false, SnapToDevicePixels to true and RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode to NearestNeighbor on the Image element.

Comment: @Clemens - it worked but partially, now I just have 2 kind of artifacts instead of many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tested it on other computer and artifacts were gone.
It was the issue with my laptop matrix - it had been replaced and wasn't fully compatible with my laptop.